# Update list of objects using LINQ

Tags: linq

Basically I am binding the List of Person to silverlight datagrid and the first row is the primary Person of id 1, each column has a checkbox and by default they are all checked for the primary person.  the second row and so forth nothing is checked, the scenario is that if the user does not want the default values then they can check other columns from other persons, but as soon as they check them the  ones from the primary person should be Unchecked automatically and vice versa, and this is just for the same column. Example column 1 is Age and column 2 is Name then the default is that they are checked for the primary person, if i dont like that data i can check Age from any other person which would uncheck the Age from the primary Person.  And I am binding the checkbox to bool value in person. So, I need a method that takes in the captured row id and the Name of  the property that was checked.

```
   List<Person> l = new List<Person>();
        l.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Age = 20, IsFirstNameSelected = false, IsLastNameSelected  = false });
        l.Add(new Person() { Id = 2, Age = 28, IsFirstNameSelected = true, IsLastNameSelected = true }); 
        l.Add(new Person() { Id = 3, Age = 22, IsFirstNameSelected = true, IsLastNameSelected = true });
```

Comment: What is your question? Your explanation is confusing to me ;-)

Comment: @BrokenGlass I edited my question with more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I properly understand the question but if you mean that for a specified person ID you want to update the properties of `IsLastNameSelected` and `IsFirstNameSelected` to have the negative of the corresponding property of the specified person ID, then this will do it:

```
int id = 1; 

IEnumerable<Person> updatedList = 
    l.Select( person => new Person()
    {
        Id = person.Id,
        Age = person.Age,
        IsFirstNameSelected = person.Id == id ? person.IsFirstNameSelected : !(l.Single( p => p.Id == id).IsFirstNameSelected),
        IsLastNameSelected = person.Id == id ? person.IsLastNameSelected : !(l.Single( p => p.Id == id).IsLastNameSelected),            
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I edited my question with explanation. Your reply only takes in the ID, i need a method that takes in ID and the name of the bool property. My example only shows 2 but i actually have 20 more of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
l.ForEach(p=> {if (p!= l.First()
                     {p.IsFirstNameSelected  = !l.First().IsFirstNameSelected }
              });
```

Something like that?

I just checked if the object is the First one or not, but you can apply other conditions as well.